# I worked on query of Elastic Search. But my result was not sorted by A to Z. So, how can I sort my result by A to Z

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I worked on many fields in order to take my result that sorted by a to z. Here is the query that I wrote:

```
  query: {
    multi_match: {
      query: "m*",
      fields: ["name", "name_mn"],
      type: "phrase_prefix",
      max_expansions: 50,
      operator: "and",
      // fields: ['title', 'authors.*name'],

      //   minimum_should_match: 3,
      //   analyzer: "standard",

      //   slop: 3,
    },
```

Result

```
    1 - Mary to Majo no Hana (score: 5.140061)
    2 - Princess Mononoke (score: 4.0831547)
    3 - Girl Like Me (score: 3.5263605)
    4 - Love and Monsters (score: 3.5263605)
    5 - Howl's Moving Castle (score: 3.5263605)
    6 - Mairimashita! Iruma-kun S01 (score: 3.1031976)
    7 - Before We Get Married (score: 3.1031976)
    8 - Rick and Morty S01 (score: 3.1031976)
    9 - Majo no Tabitabi (score: 3.0155346)
    10 - In the mood for love (score: 2.770712)
```

What I actually wanted sort is like below:

```
    1 - Mary to Majo no Hana (score: 5.140061)
    2 - Mairimashita! Iruma-kun S01 (score: 3.1031976)
    3 - Majo no Tabitabi (score: 3.0155346)
    4 - Princess Mononoke (score: 4.0831547)
    5 - Girl Like Me (score: 3.5263605)
    6 - Love and Monsters (score: 3.5263605)
    7 - Howl's Moving Castle (score: 3.5263605)
    8 - Before We Get Married (score: 3.1031976)
    9 - Rick and Morty S01 (score: 3.1031976)
    10 - In the mood for love (score: 2.770712)
```

Comment: on what basis are you performing the sorting on `name` field ?

Comment: @ESCoder here is what i wrote:

 {"name": "Usagi Drop", "name_mn": "Туулайн нулимс" },
 
    
i want to ASC this "name" by sort

Comment: but the expected result which you shared is not sorted in ascending order. Are you sorting on the basis of the first letter of the sentence ?

Comment: @ESCoder yes thats i want

Comment: then how come on 8th position sentence starting from `B`, then on 9th sentence starting from `R`, and then on 10th sentence from `I` ? This is neither in ascending nor in descending order ?

Comment: @ESCoder that sample was hard code. i just want to these results automatically sort by a to z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort the result in `ascending` order, based on the first letter of the sentence, then you need to [sort the search results in ascending order](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html)

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "m*",
      "type": "phrase_prefix"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "name.keyword": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67651064",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Before We Get Married"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Before We Get Married"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "67651064",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Girl Like Me"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Girl Like Me"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "67651064",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Howl's Moving Castle"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Howl's Moving Castle"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "67651064",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "10",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "In the mood for love"
        },
        "sort": [
          "In the mood for love"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "67651064",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Love and Monsters"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Love and Monsters"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "67651064",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Mairimashita! Iruma-kun S01"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Mairimashita! Iruma-kun S01"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "67651064",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "9",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Majo no Tabitabi"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Majo no Tabitabi"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "67651064",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Mary to Majo no Hana"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Mary to Majo no Hana"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "67651064",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Princess Mononoke"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Princess Mononoke"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "67651064",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "8",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Rick and Morty S01"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Rick and Morty S01"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: where should i wrote that mapping?

Comment: @Nautikk have you explicitly set any index mapping? And is the search result shown above, same as what you expect to get?

Comment: i used bulk index

Comment: @Nautikk then no need to set this mapping, you can directly run the search query given in the answer. Is the search result shown above, same as what you expect to get?

Comment: i added index can you look ?

Comment: is added sort below the query then i got
        `        1 - Rick and Morty S01 (score: null)
        2 - Princess Mononoke (score: null)
        3 - Mary to Majo no Hana (score: null)
        4 - Majo no Tabitabi (score: null)
        5 - Mairimashita! Iruma-kun S01 (score: null)
        6 - Love and Monsters (score: null)
        7 - In the mood for love (score: null)
        8 - Howl's Moving Castle (score: null)
        9 - Girl Like Me (score: null)
        10 - Before We Get Married (score: null)`

Comment: @Nautikk this is what I gave in the search result in the answer above. I sorted in `asc` order and you want in `desc` order. You just need to change the sort order from `asc` to `desc`

Comment: @Nautikk Have you tried with the search query I gave in the answer above ?

Comment: @Nautikk you told that you want to sort on the basis of the first letter of the sentence. Then can you explain this **First item first letter must "M"** ?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding what i want is like this  [link](https://github.com/soumilshah1995/AutoComplete-Input-Elastic-Search-Python) but many fields

Comment: sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

@ESCoder i added sort below the query then i got i want start with m

```
    1 - Rick and Morty S01 (score: null)
    2 - Princess Mononoke (score: null)
    3 - Mary to Majo no Hana (score: null)
    4 - Majo no Tabitabi (score: null)
    5 - Mairimashita! Iruma-kun S01 (score: null)
    6 - Love and Monsters (score: null)
    7 - In the mood for love (score: null)
    8 - Howl's Moving Castle (score: null)
    9 - Girl Like Me (score: null)
    10 - Before We Get Married (score: null)
```

Comment: First item first letter must "M"